# Unable to reinstall unity-desktop. currently having GNOME

Tags: dependencies, gnome-session, gnome-settings-daemon

I am tryint to install ubuntu-desktop but it shows following error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried many things but didn't able to get rid from it.

I already tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, and also `uninstall gnome-shell`. but then I become unable to login . Please help me out. I didn't able to get rid from GNOME. Many applications get crashed whenever i pressed ctrl button. cant't able to change background.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score -1):

you can reset the unity

`$ unity-reset`
`$ setsid unity`

---

if the above didnot work
try:
 
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
`sudo apt-get install unity`